# Decode base64 strings into hex strings in a file and overwrite

Tags: linux, shell, base64, hex

I have a list of `base64` strings in a file (file.txt) that I need to convert into hex. E.g.,

```
6IwwfX8Cctn85LW+vItMhw==
wIsNfYESR9Nfueo7mg3f7Q==
A+MxnRyu6kotbKPZglQ0Fg==
Jt5jNIphpmfGoFgtgM7/Sg==
sN+Q0Xcu6JHlkqdhJlM/tw==
```

Command:

```
echo -n 6IwwfX8Cctn85LW+vItMhw== | base64 -d | od -t x1 -An
```

This command works individually (albeit the spaces in between), but I need to convert through each string in the file, which has more than 500 lines.

Basically, I want the above base64 string format to be decoded to the below example hex string format:

`30aa268d130fb78a4f8cb6f300e4c760`

Is there a way that I can call each line in the file (like a *for each* command) and pipe with the base64 command to convert? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Awk` for this and run a command on the contents of the file using the `getline()` syntax

```
awk '{ cmd = "printf '%s' "$1 "| base64 -d | od -t x1 -An" }
     { while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) { gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",result); $0 = result }; close(cmd)  }1' file.txt
```

Use a temporary file for overwriting the file contents and move back the original file

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
awk '{ cmd = "printf '%s' "$1 "| base64 -d | od -t x1 -An" }
     { while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) { gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",result); $0 = result }; close(cmd)  }1' file.txt > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```sh
for b64 in $(cat e.txt); do echo "$b64" | base64 -d | od -t x1 -An | tr -d ' '; done
```

The `tr -d ' '` at the end deletes all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file.txt | while read input ; do echo -n "$input" | base64 -d | od -t x1 -An ; done
```

Comment: ...or use awk like Inian just suggested.  I lack the patience to figure out the awk script most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file.txt | while read b64
do echo -n "$b64" | base64 -d | od -t x1 -An | sed 's/[\t ]*//g'
done
```